# Django Rest Framework: permissions_classes not working

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I need to create a nested route. Which looks something like this `api/<campaign-name>/content/<content-id>`. I know there are packages ([this](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers) and [this](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions)) which creates nested routes. I have tried them and are fairly limited. So I decided to hard wire the urls. The urls and views are given below:

At urls.py

```
# contents
## detail, update, remove
url(
   r'^api/campaign/(?P<campaign>[a-z0-9-]+)/content/(?P<content>\d+)/$',
   ContentAPI.as_view({'get' : 'retrieve', 'put' : 'update', 'delete' : 'destroy'}),
   name = "content-detail"
),
## toggle content verification
url(
   r'^api/campaign/(?P<campaign>[a-z0-9-]+)/content/(?P<content>\d+)/toggle_status/$',
   ContentAPI.as_view(
      {'post' : 'toggle_status'},
      permission_classes = [Or(IsContentManager, IsContentModerator)]
      ),
      name = "content-toggle-status"
),
```

At views.py

```
class ContentAPI(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [Or(IsContentManager)]
    ... # actions and methods here
```

Everything works fine but the permissions don't seem to work. The API can be accessed without logging into the system. How to enforce the permissions in my scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was on my side. As I was generating nested route using `router.register('api/(?P<domain>[a-z0-9]+)/sub-domain/(?P<sub_domain>[a-z0-9]+), SubdomainAPI)`, I had to filter `domain` at SubdomainAPI.

So I did this at `initial()`:

```
def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):     
    self.domain = self._get_domain()
    super(SubdomainAPI, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

`self._get_domain()` checks if domain exists and raises 404 error. Since 404 error was being raised before permission checks my tests were failing.

Which should have been:

```
def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):          
    super(SubdomainAPI, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs) 
    self.domain = self._get_domain()
```

Hope this will be helpful if others stumbleupon similar problem.